# React Redux - RN slow performance

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

redux take time while returning list from mapstatetoprop to react Component in RN.

when list size increases there is delay in componenet rendering, althought i'm instantly getting the list in reducer mapstateToProps but it consume lot of time while returning prop to component.
I'm new to  RN with redux development, I'm not getting what i'm missing, Please help.

Reducer Code:

```
let defaultDataState = { 
    list: [],
};

export default reducerName = (state = defaultDataState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DATA:
            return  {
                list: action.data, 
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Component mapStateToProp Code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        list: state.reducerName.list,
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add code where you are connecting the redux to the component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to large amount of list item, Use **Flatlist** and set **initalItemToRender** as your screen size fits or  10.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it's redux causing the slow rendering. It may the components your in your render method.

Try to use perf monitor to findout what exactly is causing the slow renders. Check the [docs for performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) for more details.